# How to use stdin.h on IAR

Tags: c, iar

I have been worked on M3 circuit and wrote some simple code including identifier "uint".
I got an error saying Fatal Error[Pe1696]: cannot open source file "stdint.h".
Do I have to add the source file by myself or is there any way to solve this??

Comment: [Fixed width integer types and the `<stdint.h>` header file](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/integer) were introduced in C99.  Make sure the compiler version you use support C99 (or later).

Comment: You probably have to mention which version of the compiler you are using. IAR should supposedly support all previous standards up to C11.

Comment: IAR ARM 8.20.2 the latest version I guess. And I think I solve the problem by disabling one of the option in compiler.. Thx for the answers! And I hope I did it right to fix this one :)

Comment: If you found the solution, you should post it as proper answer, so it would be useful to others too.

Comment: it was unclicking a property 'ignore standard include directories' in preprocessor in C/C++ compiler in the option

Answer (score 0):

`stdint.h` was added to C with the year 1999 version of the standard, known as "C99". To use it, you need a compiler that supports C99 or later. Some compilers support it, but it is not enabled per default. This appears to be the case here.

The latest version of IAR supports the current standard C11, and thereby also the previous standard C99. See this link: https://www.iar.com/support/resources/articles/exploring-c11-and-c14/

Click on "C11".